Are there any other way to compute this limit without stolz?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln \binom{n}{0} + \ln \binom{n}{1} + \ln \binom{n}{2} + \dots + \ln \binom{n}{n}}{n^2}.$$
I found a proof without using the Stolz-Cesàro theorem (as follows)
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln \binom{n}{0} + \ln \binom{n}{1} + \ln \binom{n}{2} + \dots + \ln \binom{n}{n}}{n^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \ln \prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \ln \prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n+1} \right)^{\frac{n-2k+1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( 1 - \frac{2k}{n+1} \right) \ln \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n+1} \right) \right) = \int_0^1 (1 - 2x) \ln(1 - x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2}$$
But are there any other methods?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please ask a clear question, also the question should be also part of the text, not only of the title. The Addition gives a way to compute the limit in a relatively straightforward manner. We have simple reshapes, then a Riemann sum comes into play, we move to an integral, which can be computed. Which point is the problematic point? Which is the question? (A question starting with "Can we...?" usually has the answer "Yes, we can!" - but please state a more concrete question.)

This question is similar to: What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\ln\binom{n}{k} $?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
